# Excel 2016 Power query editor missing

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a user whose Excel 2016 Power query editor is missing under Data Tab-> New Query -> Query Option. In the Query Option window, Under Global - here Power Query Editor should be listed but is missing.
I checked the Addins, similars addins (compared with mine) are active, Microsoft Power Map for Excel. I have tried to re-install Office 2016 professional 64 bit, but still missing.
Any idea will be helpful
[Query OPtions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33OOk.png)
Thank you

Comment: Power Query has been integrated with excel starting with Excel 2016, so you should be able to just Data-> get data...

Comment: The user is unable to do certain tasks like her colleagues because of the missing Power Query editor option.

Comment: Did you try to update the Excel?

Comment: Hi, i installed Microsoft Office 2016 64bit Updates 2007 and problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Installed MIcrosoft Office 2016 64 bit 2007 updates -
Check Excel Data tab -> New Query Option- the Power editor option is now available.
Solved.
Check in path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\ADDINS\Microsoft Power Query for Excel Integrated\bin"
Before update No of items were 77.
After update No of items are 148.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Is the user sure they can't see this:

[image]

Or are you asking for something different?

Comment: i have now added the image in my question. Thank you.